# Unknown class 'name'

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and trying to get used to it. I have tried to make a trivial app where the user could press a button and a random number would be generated. However, when I used the variables in the code it gave me "unknown class 'get'" and "unknown class 'random'" errors. Code is as follows:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button RollButton = findViewById(id.RollButton);
        final TextView resultsTextView = findViewById(id.ResultsTV);
        final SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(id.seekBar);

        RollButton.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random(10);
            private int random = rnd.nextInt(seekBar.getProgress());
            CharSequence get = resultsTextView.getText();
            get = String.valueOf(random);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OnClickListener` looks wrong and you can't use `private` in this case. So try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button RollButton = findViewById(id.RollButton);
    final TextView resultsTextView = findViewById(id.ResultsTV);
    final SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(id.seekBar);

    RollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random rnd = new Random(10);
                int random = rnd.nextInt(seekBar.getProgress());
                CharSequence get = resultsTextView.getText();
                get = String.valueOf(random);
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: So the "unknown class 'get'" error was because I had not created that onClick method? Thank you.